# html body isn't full size of screen

Tags: html, css

I am making a website using semantic ui as my framework and everything looks fine except when I click on the sidebar icon for the sidebar menu to pop up, the background image disappears that I've set using

```
$body {
    background:url('https://lostandtaken.com/wpcontent/uploads/2010/04/141-1560x1170.jpg');
}
```

and that worked fine. But it disappears as soon as the sidebar menu pops up. I tried looking at the relationship between the sidebar and the body tag but I realized that the body height was way smaller than the size of the screen meaning that 80% of the elements were overflowing. I tried setting the body height to be 100% but that didn't work and also for some reason, chrome sets overflow to visible even if I manually set it to be hidden just to see and it also creates a pushable class. I am included a screenshot to show the height of the body according to the browser: which like 15 or 20% of the full height.[image]
 and Here is the sidebar
[image]
Here are the important part of my code

HERE IS A JSFIDDLE IF YOU WOULD LIKE TO SEE THE CODE: https://jsfiddle.net/bmb45L3p/

> HTML code

```
<!--=================================================================================================== --> 
   <body>
   <div class="ui borderless inverted fixed menu trial " style=" z-index: 10; font-family: 'IM Fell Double Pica', serif; font-size: 16px;"> 
   <a class="item icon "> <i class=" wide sidebar big icon" id="mysidebar"></i></a>
   <a class=" item" style="font-family: 'IM Fell Double Pica', serif; font-size: 20px; font-weight: bold;"> MENU </a>  
    <div class= " right menu">
    <a class="item" id="logospot"></a>
   </div> 
  </div>

 <div class ="ui sidebar compact inverted labeled icon  vertical  menu" id="theirsidebar" style="z-index: 99;">    
         <a class ="active item">
            <i class="home icon"></i>Home</a>
         <a class ="item">
            <i class="info icon"></i>About SLIDE</a>  
         <a class ="item">
            <i class="user circle outline icon"></i>Meet the Staff</a>
         <a class ="item">
         <i class="users icon"></i>Meet SLIDERS</a> 
         <a class ="item">
         <i class="block layout icon"></i>Committees</a> 
         <a class ="item">
            <i class="announcement icon"></i>Events</a> 
         <a class ="item">
            <i class="image icon" ></i>Pictures</a> 
         <a class ="item">
         <i class="write icon"></i>Apply</a>
         <a class ="item">
        <i class="mail outline icon" ></i>Contact us</a>
        <a class = "item"> 
      <i class="user icon"></i>Member Login
    </a> 
    <a class = "item"> 
        <i class="user circle icon"></i>Staff Login
    </a>
</div>

<div class="ui pusher">
<!--+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ --> 

<div class="ui container" style="display: block ; padding-top: 120px;">
<h3 style= "font-family: 'IM Fell Double Pica', serif; font-size: 60px;" class = "ui header center aligned">MEET OUR '17-'18 STAFF</h3>
```

> css

Comment: can you add a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

Remove the image CSS from body and add an Id called as `bg_img`

```
<body>
    <div id="bg_img">

    <!--menu code here-->
    <!--main content-->
    <!--footer-->

    </div>
</body>
```

add the css to id

```
html,body{margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;}
#bg_img{
  background:url('http://www.theriversouth.org/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/Light-Grey-Background-Tumblr-8.jpg');
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    background-position: center;
    min-height:100%;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much that fixed it but now i am having problem with the sidebar toggle method. When i click it, the sidebar comes up and the top bar moves to the right but when i click it again it the top bar goes left and the sidebar is still. i have to click itself more than once for it to work to actually start working correctly